# What is the best way to tap 12v from a 6x6v battery array for intermittent loads?

Tags: batteries, buck

Greetings beloved comrades,

I recently acquired a 36v golf cart that has 6 6v batteries in series.  The existing 12v accessories, mainly lights, are powered by a separate series connection to 2 of the 6v batteries.

I don't like tapping only 2 of the batteries, since prolonged usage will imbalance the batteries and possibly require individual charging.

My question is:  **Can I wire 3 12v circuits in parallel from the 6 batteries for an always active supply, or would it be better to add a separate switched 36v circuit and a buck converter to get 12v?**

I would prefer the first solution just to avoid buying a chunky switch and converter, but if the latter is better is for efficiency/battery life, I'll go that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't like tapping only 2 of the batteries, since prolonged usage will imbalance the batteries and possibly require individual charging.

Unlikely. The power draw from the accessories is probably small as compared to the engine draw.

> Can I wire 3 12v circuits in parallel from the 6 batteries for an always active supply.

Not if you still need 36V for the engine as well.

> or would it be better to add a separate switched 36v circuit and a buck converter to get 12v?

I assume you want to use the 36V from the engine supply. You can convert this down to 12V but that seems overkill and will also create some non-trivial losses (and cost)

If you are really worried about asymmetric use, simply switch the accessories to a different battery pair every 100 hours or so. If the accessories share a common ground with the engine, than you can just shuffle the batteries instead.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured.  No common ground, so I'll start swapping on a schedule.  Thank you.